# Android Studio Could not connect to server

Tags: android, android-studio

Internal HTTP server disabled. Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors

Error:Could not connect to server [30878528-8b76-4d9a-b54b-c1e807d28bb0 port:49183, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].

i have android studio 2.3.3. i am trying to resolve it ,but all effort is useless.
please help me what is the error .
thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem but I temporarily "fixed" my "Could not connect to server" error by shutting down my vpn. So if you're running a vpn, shutting it perhaps will be a temporary solution.